# Convert 'rgb()' string to hex string

Tags: typescript

The scenario is the following. I get the string from an HTML element via outerHTML and I need to convert the 'rgb(r, g, b)' part into the hexadecimal representation. I tried this with regex and it seems to work but I have a feeling there are better ways to deal with this.

One particular thing I don't like is where I directly access `color[1]` from my regex match. I'm open to any feedback.

```
private cleanupRichText(richText: string) {    
    const rx = /rgb\((.+?)\)/ig
    const color = rx.exec(richText)
    if (color !== null) {
        const hexparts = color[1].split(',').map(str => parseInt(str.trim(), 10).toString(16))
        let hexString = '#'
        hexparts.forEach(element => {
        hexString += element.length === 1 ? '0' + element : element })
        text = text.replace(/rgb\(.+?\)/ig, hexString)
    }
}
```

To give an example input:

```
'rgb(234, 112, 30)'
```

Expected output:

```
'#ea701e'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the given function does work for simple cases, it will *not* perform as expected if there are multiple colors within `richText`. The first color will override all other colors.

First, a look at your implementation:

1. Why is `richText` used in some places and the (global?) `text` in others? It looks like these are expected to be equivalent, so you should just use `richText` since it is explicitly passed in.
2. Instead of mutating the global `text`, you should return the replaced result. This makes testing the function easier and debugging much less painful.
3. Why is this a class function? It seems to have well defined inputs & outputs that does not depend on the state of any object.
4. Instead of manually padding numbers with `element.length === 1 ? '0' + element : element`, you should use `element.padStart(2, '0')` if possible. The [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Polyfill) isn't that large if it isn't supported everywhere you need it yet (IE), and it is considerably easier to read.
5. `parseInt` ignores leading whitespace, so there's no need to do `str.trim()`.
6. `String.prototype.replace` accepts a replace function, which will be called with each match. Use this to extract the rgb values instead of doing `re.exec` yourself. In the vast majority of cases, you should not need `re.exec`.
7. Should text inside the element really be converted? If you are manipulating HTML as text, you probably shouldn't be. If this `rgb()` text is in the `style` element of the element, you could be using `element.getAttribute('style')` instead.
8. What should happen if I wrote `rgb(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'asdf')`?

Here is how I would write this function, keeping your assumption that all rgb strings are well formed.

```js
function cleanupRichText(richText) {
  return richText.replace(/rgb\((.+?)\)/ig, (_, rgb) => {
    return '#' + rgb.split(',')
      .map(str => parseInt(str, 10).toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
      .join('')
  })
}

const tests = [
  ['rgb(234, 112, 30)', '#ea701e'],
  ['rgb(0, 0, 0)', '#000000'],
  ['RGB(255, 255,255)', '#ffffff'],
  ['rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(170, 170, 170)', '#000000 #aaaaaa']
]

for (const [text, expected] of tests) {
  const result = cleanupRichText(text)
  console.log(result === expected ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL', text, '->', result)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback and suggestions. The reason why I'm doing this is that I have a richtext editor in html and I have to pass the richtext string to my application in order to render a representation of this richtext. Since the richtext parser only accepts hex strings I have to do this conversion.
And yes, for the time being I assume that I only get well formed rgb strings.